# Speech recognition and speech to text on Android without any Google services

Tags: java, android, speech-recognition

I am trying to make an application which uses speech to text for command input. I am making this for Android 6.0.1 and 5.1.1. I started by trying the examples with Google services, but none of them seem to work on my devices. Most of the time there is no clear error or a crash. I have gotten the no network error while using wifi and mobile internet. For the record, I did try to use the Google app speech recognition directly, but this gave no error nor answer. After that I have tried other examples which seem to not use Google services. I would also prefer for the example to work offline, but this is more of a preference than a requirement. **I am looking for an example for android speech recognition which does not use any of the google services.**

Some of the examples that I have tried:

Did not work on a device without Google - 
https://github.com/gotev/android-speech

I got a ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_PERMISSIONS error (RECORD_AUDIO and INTERNET were allowed) -
http://www.truiton.com/2014/06/android-speech-recognition-without-dialog-custom-activity/

My main question is if such thing is at all possible and if yes then how (an example please)?

**edit 1:**
Fixed the insufficient permissions error using the example from:
https://inducesmile.com/android/android-6-marshmallow-runtime-permissions-request-example/

Now I am getting ERROR_CLIENT error (I have no idea what it means).

**edit 2:**
[the project](https://github.com/TimoLoomets/STT_V1)
[logcat output](https://gist.github.com/TimoLoomets/4f28f7f888508193de8ad73290a5afa6)

Comment: Will [Amazon Lex](https://aws.amazon.com/lex/) and/or [Amazon Transcribe](https://aws.amazon.com/transcribe/) work or do you not want any cloud based recognition?

Comment: I have no problem with cloud based recognition, but I would need an example project which I could use in Android Studio. Mainly because I am not very optimistic about getting the connection with a server to work.

Answer (score 2):

Android devices ship with Google Mobile Services and some platform level functionality, such as an implementation of a `RecognitionService` which is used by `SpeechRecognizer`.  The built-in service has support for offline functionality (and you can actually specify via option you prefer offline use).  When not using offline support, it will need `INTERNET` permission.

However, your issue is most likely with the `RECORD_AUDIO` permission, particularly on Android 6+.  Starting with Android 6 (Marshmallow, API 23) you have to use the runtime permissions model to gain access to any `dangerous` permission (which `RECORD_AUDIO` is.)

Comment: Thanks, I was able to fix the insufficient permissions error, but now I am getting ERROR_CLIENT error.

Comment: Unfortunately, that looks like a catch-all type of error, so not a lot to work with.  Provide a gist with your code as well as all logcat output and someone will be able to provide more help.

Comment: the full project: [link](https://github.com/TimoLoomets/STT_V1)
the logcat output: [link](https://gist.github.com/TimoLoomets/4f28f7f888508193de8ad73290a5afa6)

Comment: Try changing the language to `en-US` or another valid locale based variant. You might also need to use the `FREE_FORM` language model. I'd try the language first, then the other. Also, the `CALLING_PACKAGE` extra can be removed.

Comment: I tried these changes, but got the same [log](https://gist.github.com/TimoLoomets/d082168bb4fbaef24300f2e0bbc04af5). 
Firstly I removed the CALLING_PACKAGE > No change
Secondly I tried different strings (including "en-US") > No change
Thirdly I tried replacing EXTRA_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE with EXTRA_LANGUAGE > No change
Fourthly I replaced LANGUAGE_MODEL_WEB_SEARCH with LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM > No change
I also made the changes in the [github repository](https://github.com/TimoLoomets/STT_V1/blob/master/app/src/main/java/timo/stt_v1/MainActivity.java)